# Undefined Variable $name

Tags: php

Les explico que e estado haciendo una pagina web de subir y ver videos pero estoy teniendo un problema
cuando entro al inspeccionar elemento en watch.php (el código de abajo) en la parte del video me pone
que la variable $name es indefinida y pues eso el problema es que no se como definirla.

posdata: Ya intente con echo y include y no me funciona.

```
<?php
include('conexvideos.php');
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];


    $consulta = "select name from videos where id='$id'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    $name = $row['name'];
}
?>

<video width="615" height="315" controls>
<source src="watch/<?php echo $name; ?>" type="video/mp4">


</video>
```

Comment: Podrias definir esa variable arriba del if para que sea una `variable global`, porque dentro `recien la estas definiendo`

Comment: Si observas, la variable está definida dentro de un `if` y luego la usas fuera del mismo. Tienes dos opciones: 1. Definirla antes del `if` dándole un valor por defecto o dejándola vacía; 2. Meter todo el bloque de `video` dentro del `if`. Lo más lógico para este caso sería hacer lo indicado en 2.

Comment: `<?php
include('conexvideos.php');

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];


    $consulta = "select name from videos where id='$id'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    $name = $row['name'];


?>

<video width="615" height="315" controls>
<source src="watch/<?php echo $name; ?>" type="video/mp4">


</video>

<?php
}
?> ` el problema con eso es que por alguna razón la pagina se pone en blanco

Comment: Porque no estás pasando el dato `$_GET['id']`, de modo que no entra aquí: `if(isset($_GET['id'])) {` Debes verificar que el `id` se está mandando, si usas un `form` o lo pasas por URL. Puedes poner provisionalmente un `var_dump($_GET);` al principio del todo para revisar que datos están llegando.

Answer (score 1):

watch.php:

```
<?php
include('conexvideos.php');

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];


    $consulta = "select name from videos where id='$id'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    $name = $row['name'];


?>

<video width="615" height="315" controls>
<source src="watch%20/<?php echo $name; ?>" type="video/mp4">


</video>

<?php
}
?>
```

look.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Look</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Share</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="destroy()session.php">Unlogin</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <?php 

     session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    }
    else{
    header("Location: index.html");};

    include("conexvideos.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM videos";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];


        echo("<h1>Video</h1>");
        echo("<h2><a href='watch.php?id=$id'>" .$name. "</a></h2>");

    };
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si es la respuesta, seria bueno que agregaras la explicacion

Comment: ¿Esta es la respuesta? ¿Cuáles cambios hiciste? Aquí se está enviando un parametro `id` en la URL: `href='watch.php?id=$id'`, por tanto, debería asumir el `if(isset($_GET['id'])) {`.

Comment: Ya esta arreglado